# Why is the length of a string off by one on the first read of a file?

Tags: c++

I am perplexed with the way my program is performing. I am looping the following process:

1) take the name of a course from an input file

2) output the length of the name of the course

The problem is that the first value is always one less than the actual value of the string.

My first string contains 13 characters (including the colon), but `nameOfClass.length()` returns 12. The next string, the character count is 16 and indeed, `nameOfClass.length()` returns 16.

Every value after that also returns the expected value, it is only the first that returns the expected value minus 1.

Here's the (reduced) code:

```
std::ifstream inf("courseNames.txt");
int numberOfClasses = 10;
string nameOfClass;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfClasses; i++) {
    std::getline(inf, nameOfClass,':');
    std::cout << nameOfClass.length() << "\n";
}
```

The file looks like this (courseNames.txt):

```
Pre-Calculus:
Public-Speaking:
English I:
Calculus I:

...etc. (6 more classes)
```

This is what I get:

```
12

16

10

11
```

Can anyone explain this behavior of the `.length()` function?

Comment: `Pre-Calculus` has 12 characters though :)

Comment: `int numberOfClasses == 10;` is a typo, right?

Comment: Yes but 13  including the ':'. I updated with the console output.

Comment: There are 10 classes on the input file, I just didn't list them all

Comment: My guess is that you are doing this on windows, and you have \r\n as your carriage return and line feed.  Aka, a new line.  So it's picking up one of the characters after the :, and before the new line.

Comment: Thanks ChisPy, you and Rakete helped me to see this :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a problem, but you have the wrong conclusion. `std::getline` reads but doesn't output the delimiter, and so the first result is indeed 12.

It also doesn't output the delimiter for any subsequent lines, so why is there always one more? Well, look what is *after* that `:`. That's right, a new line!

```
Pre-Calculus:
             ^ a new line
```

So your `nameOfClass` variable, except for the first string, always stores an extra newline before the other characters.

The fix is easy enough, just ignore the newline after reading the string.

```
inf.ignore(); // ignore one character
```

So, not the first result was wrong, it was the only one right :)

Comment: This explains a lot. Thank you Rakete1111.

Comment: If the file is ever updated to contain other characters after the `:`, you will have to use `inf.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` instead to ignore *everything* after the `:` up to and including the line break.